# Refresh WebApp Instance Cache

Tags: azure, caching, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure WebApp with `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Always` set in order to reduce static file latency.

We have made a file change there and would like to force the instances to reload the cache.

How do I force a file cache refresh?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to refresh the cache is to restart the website.

[Azure Web apps WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION=Always requires stop and start of the site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00ee4269-f789-45ca-a30f-45ac6bc0454a/azure-web-apps-websitelocalcacheoptionalways-requires-stop-and-start-of-the-site?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old subject, but maybe it will be helpfull for someone :
If you are using C# you can add a button inside your application to remove the cache  :

```
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove((string)enumerator.Key);
}
```